# how to access the successfactors odata sales demo api

Tags: odata, sap-successfactors

https://salesdemo4.successfactors.com/odata/v2/$metadata

I tried my SAP S-id and password. Also tried email associated with S-ID that I use to login to SAP sites etc. No luck. Please advise.  I am looking for any SF odata demo site to learn their odata api. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if the question is already resolved.

You are confusing frontend (salesdemo##) and backend (apisalesdemo##) hostnames.
For getting access to backend OData, you need SuccessFactors login in form:

> nickname@clientcode

For example,

> S12345678@sales15

.

Comment: and you need the right endpoint from odata documentation (to get your instance from the correct data center)